# Adding Multiple images dynamically to TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have fairly started with IOS development and am on my first client project.

I am stuck at the following place:

so if there are 10 people's birthday this month, i need to display 10 imageviews in a single row (3 pictures, 3 pictures and 1 picture).

Can someone help me with the above. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just hover the downvote arrow to see what are reasons for downvoting, and then read your question again. People here will help or direct you on your way, not do the job for you.

Comment: @Vishal Aggarwal :- Describe ur requirement in detail.. Do u want to Display images in a table view cell ? or in a view ?

If you want to show 10 images in a table view cell then you have to implement two different approaches. 1- To customize ur table cell or 2.- Creating ‘Pulse’ style scrolling – Horizontally scrolling UITableView as a subview of UITableViewCell.

first tell me your requirement in detail After that i will try to help you . and i hope we both will get success :-)

Comment: @psycho - I am sorry if the lack of information offended you. I am complete beginner who just finished his training. As I learn I will surely get better. :)

Comment: @M.A.Khan - I think I required the initWithStyle method. I wasn't aware of it. I will work with that and post my code here if everything works out. Thank you for replying to my question though

Comment: @Vishal Aggarwal :- Describe ur requirement in detail.. Do u want to Display images in a table view cell ? or in a view ? If you want to show 10 images in a table view cell then you have to implement two different approaches. 1- To customize ur table cell or 2.- Creating ‘Pulse’ style scrolling – Horizontally scrolling UITableView as a subview of UITableViewCell. first tell me your requirement in detail After that i will try to help you . and i hope we both will get success :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add images/labels/buttons in tableview, then the simplest way is to subclass UITableViewCell.For Example if you have 5 images(didn't understand 3 pictures, 3 pictures and 1 picture ) and you want to show them in a table row then you could do something like this:

1. Add a new file in your project named CustomCell which should be the subclass of UITableviewCell like this:

   ```
   @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {  

       UIImageView *imageView1;  
       UIImageView *imageView2;  
       UIImageView *imageView3;  
       UIImageView *imageView4;  
       UIImageView *imageView5;  
   }  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView1;  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView2;  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView3;  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView4;  
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView5;  
   @end
   ```
2. And in CustomCell.m put this code like this:

   ```
   @synthesize imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4, imageView5;
   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
   {
   if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) 
       {           
           self.imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 50, 45)];
           [self.contentView addSubview:imageView1];

           self.imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 8, 50, 45)];
           [self.contentView addSubview:imageView2];

           self.imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 8, 50, 45)];
           [self.contentView addSubview:imageView3];

           self.imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 8, 50, 45)];
           [self.contentView addSubview:imageView4];

           self.imageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 8, 50, 45)];
           [self.contentView addSubview:imageView5];
       }

   return self;
   }
   ```

So you are done with subclassing of UITableViewCell.Now how to use them in your view controller?
You have to import CustomCell.h in your View Controller class.And in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method** do some thing like this:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
    {  
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

        //our custom cell  
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
        if (cell == nil) {  
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
        }  

        // Configure the cell.  

        //cell.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg1"];  
        //cell.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg2"];  
        //cell.imageView3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg3"];  
        //cell.imageView4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg4"];  
        //cell.imageView5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg5"];  
        //return cell;
```

u could use the better was :

```
    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:cell.imageView1, cell.imageView2,cell.imageView3, cell.imageView4, cell.imageView5, nil];

    for (int imageCounter = 0; imageCounter<5; imageCounter++) {
        [[imgArray objectAtIndex:imageCounter] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testImg%d", imageCounter]]];
            }  
return cell; 
}
```

this is the very prototype solution for your problem's context.
Hope it would help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try that out and will update if it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        for (int t =0; t<cell.subviews.count; t=t) {
            if (![[[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:t].class]isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"]) {
                t++;
            }
            else {
                [((UIView*)[[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:t])removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int t = 0; t<10; t++) {
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/10*t, 0, cell.frame.size.width/10, cell.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<#(NSString *)#>]];
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I don' don't know what you mean by  (3 pictures, 3 pictures and 1 picture) but you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: It looks like you're suggesting that every time the table view asks for a row... every time... even a row that's just scrolled off and then back on, you're suggesting that he allocate 10 UIImage views and pile them on as subviews.  Isn't this an overly harsh punishment for the vague question?

Comment: you would also want to remove the old ones or reuse them.

Another approach would be to create a sub class of UITableViewCell with 10 image views that you can set, however then you need a max of 10 pictures you can put in each cell.

Comment: If you want an undefined number of pictures try what I gave you and modify it to reuse objects rather than trash and remake them.

If not use http://stackoverflow.com/a/10399483/1354623